# What is the clean way to validate few method's parameters?

Tags: validation, coding-style

Let's say I have function:

```
void sayHello(String name, String surname);
```

and I want to be sure that both parameters are valid. Now I'm doing it this way:

```
if (name == null)
    throw new Exception("Name is invalid");
if (surname == null)
    throw new Exception("Surname is invalid");
```

When I'm invoking it with `sayHello(null, null);` I'm getting only information about invalid `name`.

Is there a clean way to be warned about two errors at once? By clean, I mean without two flags (or more in case of more arguments) and many `if` statements?

The snippets are in Java but I'm rather asking for a generic design solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to build error message with each validation but throw once i.e. after all validations are done.

Eg:

```
void someFunction(String param1, String param2, String param3) {
  String error = "";

  if (invalid(param1)) {
    error += "param1 is invalid";
  }
  if (invalid(param2)) {
    error += "param2 is invalid";
  }
  if (invalid(param3)) {
    error += "param3 is invalid";
  }
  if (!error.equals("")) {
    throw new Exception(error);
  }
}
```